# Python code to parse and inspect c++

Tags: c++, python

Is there a library for Python that will allow me to parse c++ code?

For example, let's say I want to parse some c++ code and find the names of all classes and their member functions/variables.

I can think of a few ways to hack it together using regular expressions, but if there is an existing library it would be more helpful.

Comment: edit: I wasn't implying that by using a regular expression I could properly parse c++, that would be absurd since it's a non-regular language. I meant that for what I need a regex might suffice.

Comment: Even for that limited case, I doubt you could do it with a regex alone. Perhaps if you narrow it down to simple, well-behaved classes with no macro or template magic (and perhaps without inheritance as well).

Comment: Have your tried http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the past I've used for such purposes [gccxml](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) (a C++ parser that emits easily-parseable XML) -- I hacked up my own Python interfaces to it, but now there's a [pygccxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygccxml/0.6.9) which should package that up nicely for you.

Comment: pygccxml looks great, i hadn't noticed it before.

Answer (score 5):

Parsing C++ accurately is light-years from something you can do with a regular expression.
You need a full C++ parser, and they're pretty hard to build.  I've been involved in building one over several years, and track who is doing it; I don't know of any being attempted *in* Python.

The one I work on is [DMS C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).
It provides not only parsing, but full name and type resolution.  After  parsing, you can basically extract detailed information about the code at whatever level of detail you like, including arbittary details about function content.

You might consider using [GCCXML](http://www.gccxml.org/), which does contain a parser, and will produce, I believe, the names of all classes, functions, and top-level variables. GCCXML won't give you any information about what's *inside* a function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little outside your question's scope perhaps... but depending on what you're trying to achieve, perhaps [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) is worth looking at.

Comment: good suggestion, it would be even more helpful if there was a library that could parse the ctags output

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried, but using the Python bindings from LLVM's Clang parser may work; see [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/).

Answer (score 0):

How about [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)?

Comment: From that site: "The pyparsing module is an alternative approach to creating and executing simple grammars".   1) c++ doesn't have a "simple" grammar.  2) Most people attempting to build a C++ parser simply fail; its a much bigger job that you might imagine.

Comment: I know it's impossible to parse C++ correctly with pyparsing, but the author of the question is not building a complier for C++ as far as I know, so pyparsing might be enough for him. Let him be the judge.

Comment: that wouldn't be helpful because i would have to write the simple grammar myself. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: ... and we don't know what he really wants to really do.  He clearly said, "parse C++".  He also said, "...find names..." but is it limited to that?  I responded to the headline question.